# Windows 8 pro installation meadia driver error

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I have a factory original Envy dv6 with 8.1, actually 8.1 was installed later. It's home edition and I want to install a clean Win 8 Pro. I've created a boot image disk and the installation starts but just after I pick the language and time, I get an media driver error.

Has anyone encountered this? Thanks.

Comment: If it came with `Windows 8 Core` (there is no such thing as `Windows 8 Home`) then you need a `Windows 8 Professional` license to do what you want.  It does not sound like you have one, you made no mention of purchasing one, the Windows 8.1 Media Creation Tool is very helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks for your reply, the current version, what ever you call it, is not a "pro" version. The .iso image of with Windows 8 I have is a Pro version with a key and all and that is the version I'm trying to install by the way of booting from a DVD method. I was to reformat the drove so that there is no residual Win 8 "core" left. This is here I'm getting the error.

Comment: Have you download the .ISO again to make sure its simply not a problem caused by a corrupt image?

Comment: Iso seems fine, I've used it on a different PC that was a new build.

Comment: I ran the installation from Windows (Win 8.1) it seems to progress fine until when it first restarts, it'll say error has occurred and reboots again, at which point it gives me options to run Win 8, Win 8.1, and Setup. Only the option Win 8.1 works. Can someone offer a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Did you download the .iso again and verify if you are booting in UEFI mode that the disk has the required EFI drivers!